# Make: Run a target based on a directory status

Tags: makefile

How can I check if a directory doesn't exists or empty then run a target?
Example:

```
.PHONY: all

all: build

build: install
    # ...
    # ...

install:
    git submodule update --recursive --remote
    bash install.sh
```

basically, I need to check for the `lib/` directory. If it exists and not empty, do nothing. If it doesn't exists or empty, run the `install` target.

Comment: And ...? You are not attempting to do that in your code.

Comment: Because I'm not sure how to do it.

Comment: Are `build` and `install` also phony targets? Is `all` the default goal? Is it the `install` recipe (`git submodule...`) that creates and populates `lib`? Please answer by editing your question, not in comments, pictures, external links...

Answer (score 0):

I'd go for something like this (untested):

```
# if lib is empty, run install
ifeq ($(wildcard lib/*),)
    git submodule update --recursive --remote
    bash install.sh
endif
```

It's not technically running a target, but I reckon it's what you ask for.

For running an actual target you'd setup prerequisites accordingly:

```
# some program using something in lib/
program: lib/libhello.a

# "making" the lib
lib/libhello.a:
    git submodule update --recursive --remote
    bash install.sh
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure I understand the role of the `build` target. Let's assume it is another intermediate phony target. Let's also assume that your default goal is `all`, and you want `all` to fire `build`, that itself fires `install` if and only if `lib` does not exist or is empty. Finally, let's assume that it is:

```
git submodule update --recursive --remote
bash install.sh
```

that creates `lib` and populates it. You could use a dummy empty file to mark that the `lib` directory exists and is not empty. Example:

```
.PHONY: all build install

all: build

build: install
    # ...
    # ...

install: lib/.exists

lib/.exists:
    git submodule update --recursive --remote
    bash install.sh
    touch "$@"
```